# wordpress sidebar vertical spacing between Li

Tags: css, wordpress

In Wordpress ,left sidebar li text is too long and it wraps which causes vertical space in between li's  to look uneven. How can I correct this? Any help is appreciated. 
I've attached screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the URL of your site so we can see / analyse the code? Nobody could tell from a picture I guess. On my WP page it works fine...

Comment: Please include your code and preferably a demo reproducing the error. Further, the `li` elements seem to me to be evenly spaced. What uneven spacing are you talking about?

Comment: @Nightstalker , TylerH   thanks your comments. This is the [url](http://acodediary.com). I tried playing with line-height as suggested by Slavik but didnt help much. Right now line-height is 1 . Also it looks fine in chrome but not on FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `font-size: 11px;` in `.sidebar-left a` And add it into `.sidebar-left li`. Finally looks like this.

```
.sidebar-left li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.sidebar-left a {
  color: #232324;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at css attributes

```
line-height
padding-top
padding-bottom
margin-top
margin-bottom
```

recommend try to change li's line-height.